# Preventing to delete mysql records by php

Tags: php, html

I have made a table called 'Gebruikers'. The table looks like this:

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| gebruikersnaam | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| wachtwoord     | varchar(1024)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bibliotheekid  | int(10) unsigned | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email          | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This table stores the login id and password of users and the admin. The column 'gebruikersnaam' defines the login id and also if a record is an admin or user.

The admin has a list of all users (even himself), and is able to delete them (including himself).

See code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Gebruiker";   
$resultaat = mysql_query($sql);
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>gebruikersnaam</th>
        <th>wachtwoord</th>
        <th>bibliotheekid</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
    while(list($id, $gebruikersnaam, $wachtwoord, $bibliotheekid, $email) = mysql_fetch_row($resultaat)){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $gebruikersnaam; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $wachtwoord; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $bibliotheekid; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<a href=\"gebruiker_verwijderen.php?id=$id\">verwijderen</a>"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<a href=\"gebruiker_wijzigen.php?id=$id\">wijzigen</a>"; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo "<a href=\"gebruiker_wijzigen_ww.php?id=$id\">wachtwoord</a>"; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php     
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

I want to prevent that the admin could delete itself by not giving a `<a href=\"gebruiker_verwijderen.php?id=$id\">verwijderen</a>` in the while list if the value of '$gebruikersnaam' equals 'admin'. I don't know how to do that correctly.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Use sessions to store who the current user is and check if the user being deleted is the user in the session?

Comment: Ok, why is this question not usefull ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you actually answered your own question:

```
<td><?php
    if ('admin' != $gebruikersnaam) {
        echo "<a href=\"gebruiker_verwijderen.php?id=$id\">verwijderen</a>";
    }
?></td>
```

This will print out an empty `<td>` if it is an admin.  Note that this applies for *any* admin (that is an admin cannot delete another admin).  Presumably you also have a session identifier for the logged in user that you can compare to check whether they are also an admin.

You probably also want to add a restrictin on `gebruiker_verwijderen.php` that prevents deleting of admin/logged-in users as well.